# Shortcut to turn off phone when phone is full charge

Tags: ios, iphone, sirishortcuts

I'm using Shortcut and want to set automation that turns off phone when battery level equals 100% (full charge) . so i select new automation and battery level choice, But how may i define phone shutdown to as an action ?

Comment: You can't.  Shutting down the phone is not an available action.

Comment: So is there any way to stop charging at the time battery level is 100% ? by using shortcut or any other ways ?

Comment: The phone will stop charging when it reaches 100%.  iPhones have sophisticated battery life management

Comment: But when i wake up (morning) it is always changing at level 100% and charging has not stopped.I think it's because of that phone uses battery after full charge.

Comment: What do you mean "it hasn't stopped"? How do you know?  The battery management system will stop charging when the battery is full, but it will still show a charging symbol on the battery because external power is still connected. This has zero effect on battery life.

Comment: one question, battery is full at midnight (e.g 4:00 AM) , after that phone is using battery so battery starts discharging so it's 95% at 9:00 AM, when i wake up i see battery is always 100% , so phone is charged again from 95%, am i right ?

Comment: No, when the battery is full, the phone stops charging the battery and it just runs off the wall power. It doesn't start running of the battery until you unplug the charger.

Comment: Thanks, but 2 question: 1- If phone stops charging the battery and it runs off the wall power , how it remains at 100% after hours ? 2 - Why ios has an option in "Battery health" to optimize battery charging?

Comment: If it is running off wall power, why would the battery discharge? Why wouldn't it remain at 100%?  If you enable optimised battery charging then iOS can charge the battery more slowly to improve battery life. It learns from your typical usage patterns to charge at a slower rate overnight but still be ready for you in the morning. If you don't want to wait then you can turn this feature off.

Comment: Remember Apple has sold billions of devices and a large number of these are reporting analytics on many aspects including their battery.  Apple probably knows more about battery life management than any other company in the world.

Comment: You say, when phone is 100%, phone stop charging , ok , but you say it will run off wall power, but we see phone will stay 100% after hours , apps are using battery , so why it doesn't discharge? maybe because it's using wall power ?

Comment: How would apps be using the battery if the phone is plugged into the charger?  The charger is more than capable of running the phone. No power will be taken from the battery when the phone is connected to external power

Comment: So question remains ,If phone will use wall power after full charge , why apple created optimized battery charging? why apple intend to slow down charging process ?

Comment: If your phone is charging overnight while you are sleeping it doesn't make any difference to you if it is fully charged by 2am or 5am, as long as it is fully charged when you get up, but charging more slowly does prolong the life of the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you jailbreak your iPhone and code a jail-broken app that has your iPhone spring it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks but i  need a way without jailbreak. a way to stop charging after full charge .

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that can be done using the Shortcuts app alone.

However this is possible by a different approach. You would need an outlet or a plug that is compatible with Apple HomeKit to do this. Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M3PK5WH) would work. Different versions are available for different countries/types.

Then you create your automation inside Shortcuts and first get the current battery status. This will return a number between 0 and 100. Add a condition to your Shortcut to evaluate this value. If your battery status is equal to 100, the plug that is charging your device should be turned off. Add a Home action to your shortcut and select your Plug as a device to automate. Switch it to off and your phone will stop charging.

However iOS has some intelligent charging mechanisms built in. So I don’t see why someone would need this kind of automation.